# Invoke-Command only running on the last node in an array

Tags: powershell, session, invoke-command

I have a total of 3 servers with 2 folders on each server that have an .exe I need to execute from their respective locations.  Below is my current code.  What is happening is the output is showing the code gets run but when I log into those servers, the .exe is not running.  However, every time the last node works perfectly fine.  I'm lost.

Here is my current code:

```
    Foreach ($server in $NodeArray) {
    # $NodeArray consists of server1, server2 and server3

        $Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $server -Authentication Negotiate -Credential $HPCSlaveCreds -ErrorAction Stop
    
        $Scriptblock = {
                param ($MasterNode, $ControlFile)
                
                $FolderName = (Get-ChildItem 'C:\HPC' | select -last 1).name
                $Path = (Get-ChildItem "C:\HPC\$FolderName" -Recurse -Filter "Agent*").Name
                
                foreach ($agent in $Path) {
                    
                    $PestArguments = "$ControlFile /H ${MasterNode}:4004"
                    Write-Host "Starting Beopest on $env:COMPUTERNAME - $PestArguments"
                    Start-Process -FilePath "pestpp-ies.exe" -WorkingDirectory "C:\HPC\$FolderName\$agent" -ArgumentList $PestArguments

                }       
            
         }
        
         Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock -ArgumentList $MasterNode, $ControlFile

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: can you show us the real value of $NodeArray

Comment: Hey Frederic, $NodeArray pulls the IPAdresses field from a json file.  So $NodeArray = @('172.22.xxx.xxx','172.22.xxx.xxx','172.22.xxx.xxx')

Comment: Just as a test, have you tried changing the order of the servers and see if it's still the last server that works? It *could* be a problem on the specific servers which means only one of them works regardless of its position in the list, rather than the symptom being that only exactly the last server works...

Comment: The servers in question are built via a form the user fills out for a High Performance Compute setup.  Each server is built using the same template so they are all identical builds.  In testing I've run 3 tests so far and in all 3 the last server would always work.  In the 3 test all servers were different IPs given at time of creation.

Comment: The last line `Invoke-Command -Session ...` is inside the $Scriptblock that it is calling.

Comment: Daniel, you're right, that was a mistype.  Should be after the bracket below it.  I do have it correct in my .ps1 though.  Also missing the end bracket of the foreach loop, ill update.

Comment: If you are looking for **folders** append switch `-Directory` to your  `Get-ChildItem` cmds. Otherwise, it could also pick up **files** and then your WorkingDirectory will be wrong.

Comment: Is the exe moving around?  
Or why don you need the calculate the part of the path using `(Get-ChildItem 'C:\HPC' | select -last 1).name`